# Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'BDR_POST-BI ( SCT'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have store procedure that can run smoothly before. But right now when I try to run it get me that error "Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 84
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'BDR_POST-BI ( SCT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 84
Incorrect syntax near 'BDR_POST-BI ( SCT'.". This is my store procedure by the way

```html
USE [dbbib]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_QuerySummary]    Script Date: 10/4/2018 4:13:57 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:  <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_QuerySummary]
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(FailureMode as varchar) + ']',
'[' + cast(FailureMode as varchar)+ ']')
FROM (SELECT    distinct    FailureMode FROM tblBIB )as s
GROUP BY FailureMode
order by FailureMode

DECLARE @columns2 VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @columns2 = COALESCE(@columns2 + ',isnull([' + cast(FailureMode as varchar) + '],0) as ['+ cast(FailureMode as varchar) +']',
'isnull([' + cast(FailureMode as varchar)+ '],0) as ['+ cast(FailureMode as varchar)+']')
FROM (SELECT    distinct    FailureMode FROM tblBIB )as s
GROUP BY FailureMode
order by FailureMode

DECLARE @columns3 VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @columns3 = COALESCE(@columns3 + '+isnull([' + cast(FailureMode as varchar) + '],0)',
'isnull([' + cast(FailureMode as varchar)+ '],0)')
FROM (SELECT    distinct    FailureMode FROM tblBIB where FailureMode not like 'QUARANTINE' and FailureMode not like 'BARE' and FailureMode not like 'PM' and FailureMode not like 'TEMPORARY HOLD_SET B')as s
GROUP BY FailureMode
order by FailureMode

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

SET @query = '

declare @table table (BibType nvarchar(100), CntActive int)

insert into @table
select BibType,count(BibID) as CntActive from(
select substring(BibID,1,6) as BibType, BibID from(
select * ,
case
when len(BibID)>1   and len(BIBRecall)>1 then 1
when len(BibID)=1   and len(BIBRecall)>1 then 1
else 0
end as selection
from(
SELECT        isnull(a.BibID,0) as BibID, isnull(tblBIB.BIBRecall,0)as BIBRecall
FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT BibID
                          FROM            Orca.dbo.tblLatestTurnAllBIB
                          WHERE        (CONVERT(date, DTDone) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))) AS a full outer JOIN
                         tblBIB ON a.BibID = tblBIB.BIBRecall
)as s
)as s where selection=0
)as q group by BibType



declare @table2 table ( CntActive int, rn int)

insert into @table2
select count(BibID) as CntActive ,0 as rn from(
select substring(BibID,1,6) as BibType, BibID from(
select * ,
case
when len(BibID)>1   and len(BIBRecall)>1 then 1
when len(BibID)=1   and len(BIBRecall)>1 then 1
else 0
end as selection
from(
SELECT    isnull(a.BibID,0) as BibID, isnull(tblBIB.BIBRecall,0)as BIBRecall
FROM            (SELECT DISTINCT BibID
                          FROM            Orca.dbo.tblLatestTurnAllBIB
                          WHERE        (CONVERT(date, DTDone) = CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))) AS a full outer JOIN
                         tblBIB ON a.BibID = tblBIB.BIBRecall
)as s
)as s where selection=0
)as q 


select*,row_number()over(order by total desc) as rn from(
SELECT Device,DeviceType,'+ @columns3 +' as Total,isnull(q.CntActive,0) as CntActive,'+ @columns2 +',q.BibType
FROM (SELECT        a.DeviceType, tbldevtypev2.Device, a.Cnt, a.FailureMode
FROM            (SELECT        DeviceType, COUNT(BIBRecall) AS Cnt, FailureMode
                          FROM            tblBIB
                          GROUP BY DeviceType, FailureMode) AS a left outer JOIN
                         tbldevtypev2 ON a.DeviceType = tbldevtypev2.[BIB Type]
)as a
PIVOT
(
MAX(Cnt)
FOR [FailureMode]
IN (' + @columns + ')
)
AS a left outer  join @table q on a.DeviceType = q.BibType
)as p 


union  all


SELECT ''Grand Total'' as Device,'''' as DeviceType,'+@columns3+' as Total,*,'''' as BibType  from(
Select isnull(i.CntActive,0) as CntActive,o.* from(
SELECT '+@columns2+',0 as rn
FROM (
SELECT        COUNT(BIBRecall) AS Cnt, FailureMode
                          FROM            tblBIB
        
                          GROUP BY  FailureMode 
)as a
PIVOT
(
MAX(Cnt)
FOR [FailureMode]
IN (' + @columns + ')
)
AS p
)as o full outer join @table2 i on o.rn= i.rn
)as p

'

EXECUTE(@query)
END
```

Comment: Maybe you have ' or " characters on a "line String". Consider use parameters, or perform a line.Replace (""","") etc. to remove them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting data into a database consider using [SQL parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2) to avoid [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = line
```

I would also consider implementing [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement):

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished with them. This makes them available for other code to use.

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(str),
      cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2 ([a], [roll], [c]) VALUES (1, 2, @line)", con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = line

    con.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  End Using
```

I would also consider looping through the file inside the `Using` statement to save creating the SQL objects over and over again:

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(str),
      cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table2 ([a], [roll], [c]) VALUES (1, 2, @line)", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.VarChar)

    con.Open()

        Using sr As New StreamReader(path)
            Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
                cmd.Parameters("@line").Value = sr.ReadLine
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

<sub>This code is untested, I haven't the environment but it should give you something to work with.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

what is the value of line?

try

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into table2 ([a], [roll],[c]) values (1, 2, '''" & line & "''')", con)
```

Comment: Data of the log file

Comment: in the data of the log file you have the sign ' or the sign ". Try with double or triple ' like i posted

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use parameters. Check you database to get the correct 'SqlDbType'

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("insert into table2 ([a], [roll],[c]) values (1, 2, @line);", con))
cmd.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = line
```